# How to get inverse of a lerp function

Tags: javascript, math

```
speed = Math.Lerp(speed, goalSpeed, time);
```

This code increases speed close to goalSpeed almost immediately and then slows down as it approaches it. How can I flip this around so that it accelerates slowly and then begins to speed up as it approaches it?

This is probably a simple answer, it's been evading me for ten minutes though. :)

Comment: Look at the code in the library and reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with `1%` of `goalSpeed` below code helps you increase speed slowly then speeds up:

```
speed = 0.01 * goalSpeed; // Initial speed
speed = speed + Math.Lerp((goalSpeed - speed), goalSpeed, time);
```

//Round when `speed` crosses `goalSpeed` and stop.

Comment: Works but not quite as flexible as needed. Ended up with this solution instead: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/425501/how-to-get-inverse-of-a-lerp-function.html